# Bulk SQL insert in Wordpress usermeta table

Tags: mysql, wordpress, join, insert

I have an extra table in my Wordpress DB with the structure shown below

```
CREATE TABLE `rsvp` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`came` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `rsvp_id` (`uid`),
KEY `came` (`came`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
--Other fields edited out for brevity
--uid here is the same as user_id in the Wordpress usermeta table
```

I would like to create an additional row (meta_key = teamapps, meta_value = 1) in the `wp_usermeta` table for each user in the `rsvp` table who has `came = "1"`.  I only have about 15 entries in the `rsvp` table  so I could at a pinch simply do a sequence of

```
INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta` (user_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES('uid','teamapps','1');
```

I could also write a simple PHP script to automate the job for me.  However, I am wondering whether there isn't a pure SQL way to do this - query the `rsvp` table to establish all users who have `came = 1` and then use the results of that query to do the insert in the `wp_usermeta` table.

I suspect this can somehow be done via a `JOIN` but SQL is pretty much my weak suite so I have no idea how I should write the relevant SQL.  Perhaps someone here might be able to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `INSERT ... SELECT` should do what you're after.  The idea is to create a `SELECT` statement that returns the values you want to insert, then preface it with an `INSERT` clause containing the column list.  Something like (untested):

```
INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta` (user_id,meta_key,meta_value)
SELECT uid,'teamapps','1'
FROM `rsvp`
WHERE came = "1"
```

Note that that's not re-runnable, so check the `SELECT` portion returns only what you're after.  And/or add another `NOT EXISTS` condition to your `WHERE` clause to check for existing rows in `wp_usermeta`.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO `DATABASE`.`wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`,
  `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '9999', 'wp_capabilities', 
  'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}'), (NULL, '9999', 'wp_user_level', '10');
```